# Nginx Tornado and Flask - What's a good start/stop script and keep-alive method

Tags: nginx, tornado, flask, server-configuration

I've set up a Flask application to run on a tornado server backed by nginx. I've written a couple of bash scripts to reload server configuration when a new version is deployed, but I am unhappy with them. Basically what I have is:

### to start the server (assuming in project root)

```
# this starts the tornado-flask wrapper
python myapp.py --port=8000 # .. some more misc settings

# this starts nginx
nginx
```

### to stop it

```
pkill -f 'myapp.py'
nginx -s stop
```

### to restart

```
cd $APP_ROOT
./script/stop && ./script/start
```

Many times these don't work smoothly and I need to manually run the commands. Also, I'm looking for a way to verify the service is alive, and start it up if it's down. Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I am looking at similar setup, any chance that you have written blog post?

Comment: Errgh, sorry :). I ended up using Gunicorn instead of Tornado due to some blocking issues with MySQL/Tornado long queries. My setup is fairly plain and could use a lot of pulishing. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3704416). You can then use the `update-rc.d` command to set it up on machine start-up, or run them manually. I also used the docs in linode [regarding nginx](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/installation), and applied some of the info [in this railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) (the parts about server config). Hope this helps some.

Comment: Specifically, [this page](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/installation/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#sph_create-an-init-script-to-manage-nginx) describes setting up an init script for nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is what you are looking for.

It's what I use to manage my [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) apps along with some other processing daemons.
It will daemonize, handle logging, pid files... Pretty much everything you need.